# How do I route in client-side blazor with a string route parameter containing dots (.)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, blazor, blazor-client-side

Hi there stack**overflow**!

I am using Client side Blazor and have stumbled upon a tricky section regards to routing with strings and dots (.). I wish to route from an admin control page to a page with the following route: `@page "/ManageGradingExamResults/{StudentEmail}"`. I tested such with this request: `https://localhost/ManageGradingExamResults/1234@high.school.nz`, but I get a not found. If I change the razor route to `@page "/ManageGradingExamResults/{*StudentEmail}"` I end up with the following exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid template 'ManageGradingExamResults/{*StudentEmail}'. The character '*' in parameter segment '{*StudentEmail}' is not allowed.`. I tried that due to the similarities in cshtml pages.

I have found that I can route with integers but have had no luck with strings. I also have come across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-parameters) Microsoft doc explaining rout params and suggesting the ** in my page route. This allows me into my page however i then need to use the ? before my email in the request, the page does not load with my data as I can see it did not pull the parameter into my variable. 
 Any suggestions or help with routing in client side Blazor would be greatly appreciated!

*Request Code:*

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/ManageGradingExamResults/?{student.Email}");
```

*Request URL:*

```
https://localhost/ManageGradingExamResults/?1234@high.school.nz
```

*Razor page route:*

```
@page "/**ManageGradingExamResults/{StudentEmail}"
@page "/ManageGradingExamResults"
```

*My Variable:*

```
@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string StudentEmail { get; set; }
...
```

Comment: Maybe ask in here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13247 Issue is still open.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and decided to move the problematic parameter to a query string parameter. Note that this is only supported in Blazor .NET 6.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#query-strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the documentation you have shared:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-parameters)

> In Blazor Server apps, the default route in _Host.cshtml is / (@page "/"). A request URL that contains a dot (.) isn't matched by the default route because the URL appears to request a file. A Blazor app returns a 404 - Not Found response for a static file that doesn't exist. To use routes that contain a dot, configure _Host.cshtml with the following route template:
>   `@page "/{**path}"`

[Based on routing in .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> During link generation, the routing system encodes the value captured in a double-asterisk (**) catch-all parameter (for example, {**myparametername}) except the forward slashes

So this should do the trick for you

```
@page "/ManageGradingExamResults/{**StudentEmail}"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is for Blazor Server Side whereas the question is for Blazor Client Side

Answer (score 6):

Blazor documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#routing-with-urls-that-contain-dots) suggests modifying the Fallback file route on the server.

This is not possible when hosting from Azure Blob static websites or Amazon S3. Since the assumption that a dot is a file when it is on the **right most end** of the uri, consider moving the parameter.

Param with dot on the right-most end of the URI. This will result in 404 since the `StudentEmail` param contains a dot and will be routed as a file (and assuming you cannot modify the server Startup.Config).

```
@page "/ManageGradingExamResults/{StudentEmail}"
```

**Move the param so it is not on the right most end of the URI:**
This will route correctly and pass the `StudentEmail` param to the component.

```
@page "/GradingExamResults/{StudentEmail}/Manage"
```